# Why are code tags being inserted by liquid/jekyll and how do I remove them?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I want to create a list of recent authors for a blog I'm developing using Jekyll.

I'm taking the list of recent authors and looking up each item in a yml data sheet I've set up that lists each author and their bio, name and email etc.

I'm able to extract the information I want but when it renders in the browser it's in between `<code>` tags.

The problem bit is

```
{% assign recent_leader = site.data.leaders[dedupped_leader] %}

        {{ recent_leader.name }}
        {{ recent_leader.bio }}
```

The assign statement seems to cause the entire loop contents to drop into a code block.

How do I get rid of the `<code>` tags? I'm wondering if there's just a comma out of place somewhere or ...

Here is the rest of the code for the page.

```
{% comment %}First loop captures leaders from the last three months {% endcomment %}

{% for post in site.posts %}

 {% capture postDateSeconds %}{{post.date | date: "%s"}}{% endcapture %} 
 {% capture siteTimeMinusTwelveWeeks %}{{site.time | date: "%s" | minus: 7260000}}
 {% endcapture %}

{% if postDateSeconds >= siteTimeMinusTwelveWeeks and post.date <= site.time %}
 {% capture indexes %}{{ indexes | append: forloop.index | append: "," }}{% endcapture %}
 {% capture leaders %}{{ leaders | append: post.leader | append: "," }}{% endcapture %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}



{% comment %}Split the captured loop into its own array {% endcomment %}

{% assign leaders_array = leaders | split: "," %}


{% comment %} initialise a new array for dedupped list{% endcomment %}

{% assign dedupped_leaders = "" %}

{% comment %} if the leaders name is in the new array already remove it. Then add the name. This makes sure the name is on the list just once. {% endcomment %}

{% for leader in leaders_array %}

{% if dedupped_leaders contains leader %}
{% assign leader_and_comma = leader | append: "," %}
{% capture dedupped_leaders %}{{dedupped_leaders | remove_first: leader_and_comma }}{% endcapture %}
{% endif %}
{% capture dedupped_leaders %}{{dedupped_leaders | append: leader | append: ","}}{% endcapture %}


{% endfor %}


{% comment %}Split the captured loop into its own array {% endcomment %}

{% assign dedupped_leaders_array = dedupped_leaders | split: "," %}

{% for dedupped_leader in dedupped_leaders_array %}

{% assign recent_leader = site.data.leaders[dedupped_leader] %}

        {{ recent_leader.name }}
        {{ recent_leader.bio }}

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% assign recent_leader = site.data.leaders[dedupped_leader] %}

        {{ recent_leader.name }}
        {{ recent_leader.bio }}
```

If you do this in a markdown file, it will output code block ([see kramdown documentation](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#code-blocks))

If you don't want code block, do :

**no line break after a not indented line**

```
{% assign recent_leader = site.data.leaders[dedupped_leader] %}
    {{ recent_leader.name }}
    {{ recent_leader.bio }}
```

or **two space indentation**

```
{% assign recent_leader = site.data.leaders[dedupped_leader] %}

  {{ recent_leader.name }}
  {{ recent_leader.bio }}
```